# Error creating axis d3.js

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I've been wrestling with this problem for quite a while now. I want to create an x-axis, so I used the following code:

```
var w = 1024,
    h = 1024,
    padding = 20,
    fill = d3.scale.category20();

var vis = d3.select("#chart")
  .append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);


d3.json("force.json", function(json) {


  //Create array of dates for the x-axis
  var dates = json.nodes.map(function(d) {
    return Date.parse(d.date);
  });

  console.log(dates)

  // Create scale from the array of dates
  var scale = d3.time.scale()
                  .domain(dates)
                  .range([padding, w - padding]);

  console.log(scale(dates));

  var axis = d3.svg.axis(); 
//more code below, but error gets called at the line above this comment.
}
```

However, I get the following error returned consistently:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'axis'
```

This is very perplexing, as I was simply following the d3 API at https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes.

Would somebody kindly point out where I'm going wrong?

(for reference, `force.json` is the data I am working with)

Comment: Is it firing your scale before it's finished loading your data? I would expect so, but I wouldn't expect it to throw an error on axis. Are you calling axis somewhere after assigning scale to it and that's where the error comes from? I'd suggest putting all your code into the callback for d3.json and seeing if it works there.

Comment: Thank you for your response, Elijah. To address your first question: I don't think it's trying to construct the scale before finishing loading the data, as the `dates` array is successfully constructed (as by reading the console).

Comment: To address your second question: I'm creating the axis for the first time after calling `d3.json`. I have edited the code to indicate the line in which the error message referenced.

Comment: You're right, I misread the }) end of the map function and thought that was the end of your callback in d3.json. I can't imagine why the above would happen, unless you overwrote d3.svg.axis() somewhere, but I'd imagine you would see that.

Comment: Right, I did a quick cmd-F (I'm on a Mac) in Sublime, and there's only 1 instance of `d3.svg.axis()`.

Comment: Try moving around that line, towards the beginning of the file, and see what happens.

Comment: What do you see when you `console.log(d3.svg)`? I suspect something overwrites this object with another value. That would happen either in a cryptic, indirect way, or literally by running `d3.svg = ...` somewhere in your code.

Comment: meetamit: I think I see where things might be going wrong. I see `arc`, `area`, `chord`, `diagonal`, `line`, `mouse`, `symbol` and `touches` functions, but no `axis` function. This happens when I put `console.log(d3.svg)` right before the offending line of code. I will now try putting it right at the top of the code...

Comment: And it's the same set of functions, no `axis()` function present in the console log.

Comment: OK, I think I solved the problem. My downloaded version of `d3.js` does not include the axis function. When I reference Mike Bostock's version in the HTML file, it works out fine.